# What does this simple circuit do?

Tags: mosfet, low-power

[image]

This is a power circuit. I have no idea what it is trying to protect.

Answer (score 11):

It's reverse polarity protection in case the battery is connected incorrectly. More here: https://www.edn.com/reverse-voltage-protection-for-battery-chargers/

Comment: Thank you, that was really helpful.