# Filtering USB +5V and filtering battery (also +5V) before and after LDO

Tags: mosfet, resistors, filter, inductor, ldo

I have a development board project where I want to use USB as the power source when plugged in and then switch off the battery - and vice versa. Then I am running it through a 3.3V fixed LDO (AMS1117-3.3V) to power an ESP32 chip.

The problem is with the filtering; I am not sure that this is good enough. Any suggestions on how to improve (if this even works) because I am not sure about the filter since I added the 10KΩ resistor for the power switch (MOSFET).

[image: Schematic - VBUS is the USB 5V and BAT is the 5V from the battery.]

This was the original schematic but it has since been updated to the one below. Realized that the diode between the 10uH inductor and the LDO did not really serve the purpose that I thought it did.

[image]

I also changed the value of C2 from 10uF to 470nF and C3 from 10uF to 33uF. Let me know if this could be improved - other values, different components etc. The only thing is that I do not want is to use too many components!

Comment: Your FET looks backwards (body diode always on). I think the diode between the inductor and the AMS is inadvisable - what's its purpose? Max capacitance allowed on VBUS is 10uF and you've got 20uF. Not sure the inductor is a good idea either - could introduce instability in regulator and you shouldn't really need the extra filtering.

Comment: We don't know if it is good enough, because you don't say for what purpose it needs to be good enough, and how much good enough is for that purpose.

Comment: Isn't it facing the right way, @td127 (the FET)? When there are +5V on VBUS it will shut off the +5V from the BAT. The diode is a mistake on my part! Do not really know why I placed it there - had an idea in my head when I drew the schematic.

Can you elaborate further on how it could cause instability? Quite with this kind of filter design (and the AMS1117).

Comment: Good enough is maybe a bad way of explaning what I want, @Justme  - I just want to know if it is possible to filter more efficiently with the same number of components.

Comment: The AMS1117 has a PSRR of minimum 60 dB.  Unless your USB Vbus is extremely noisy, you shouldn't need to put too much effort into filtering it.

Comment: The VBUS might get noisy, @vir - the board is supposed to be something that our fieldworkers can use when they are out doing jobs and I do not know how noisy it could get elsewhere. So as you say I do not want to put too much effort into it, but I want it to be as good as possible with about the same amount of components as used in the schematic! :-)

Comment: It's not necessary to filter USB, although if this is some very sensitive analog circuit I might consider a slightly better LDO. Not that expensive to get a lot of rejection in the 10k-100k band that USB tends to be noisy in.

Comment: I believe the Source and Drain of the FET are swapped. The controlling voltage is between the Gate and Source, the Source being the predicatable, fixed VBAT voltage, not to indeterminate, switched voltage on the regulator side.

Comment: @td127 it looks weird but that's the correct orientation for reverse polarity protection: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/588808/reverse-polarity-voltage-protection-using-p-mosfet

Comment: Guess there is nothing wrong with how it is done in the second picture then, @vir. Looked a bit more into it as well - I see what you mean td127, but it is because I cannot let any voltage onto the BAT from VBUS! :-D

Comment: @user1850479 can you recommend (or have any in mind) for this?

Comment: I stand corrected on the FET polarity, thanks.