What is the purpose of this transistor?
I would like to Know the purpose of this transistor. Someone knows the name of the circuit topology??


In the picture is not visible but the GATE pin is connected to ground.

https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/588808/reverse-polarity-voltage-protection-using-p-mosfet

@A.V. In the picture is not visible but the GATE pin is connected to ground. ... please do not comment on your own question...if you have anything to add, then edit the question
